# Get MAX() minus MIN() for each GROUP BY column in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Not sure how to word this, but essentially, I'd like to write a query that outputs, for each "LocationDescription", the result of its MAX(StatusDateTime) minus its MIN(StatusDateTime), and if that's even possible with one query, pie in the sky output would also include the total number of rows for that given LocationDescription.

Sample Data:

```
LocationDescription StatusDateTime
Site 1              2/6/20 10:35:34.027
Site 1              2/6/20 10:35:33.823
Site 1              2/6/20 10:35:33.183
Site 1              2/6/20 10:35:32.387
Site 2              2/6/20 10:35:53.500
Site 2              2/6/20 10:33:06.917
Site 2              2/6/20 10:33:06.300
Site 2              2/6/20 10:34:44.083
Site 2              2/6/20 10:34:52.410
Site 2              2/6/20 10:34:40.503
Site 2              2/6/20 10:34:49.710
Site 2              2/6/20 10:35:53.753
Site 3              2/6/20 10:32:38.253
Site 3              2/6/20 10:36:08.987
Site 3              2/6/20 10:36:08.013
Site 3              2/6/20 10:36:06.060
Site 3              2/6/20 10:32:45.890
```

Ideal Output (the durations are ballparked below based on sample data above):

```
LocationDescription DurationDifference TotalRecords
Site 1              00:00:02.000       4
Site 2              00:02:47.000       8
Site 3              00:03:21.000       5
```

Is this possible with 1 query?

EDIT: My ultimate goal with this is to attempt to say "X number of records per second for Site 1", "X number of records per second for Site 2", etc. This is a performance-based metric I plan to use on a dashboard to show how quickly things are being healthchecked.

Comment: Do you need the duration difference in this format, or would you also accept reporting the difference in some fixed time unit, e.g. seconds?

Comment: seconds would be perfect actually! (I added some additional info that might make that part clearer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try aggregating by the location description, then use `DATEDIFF` in seconds to find the difference between the min and max status times.

```
SELECT
    LocationDescription,
    DATEDIFF(second, MAX(StatusDateTime), MIN(StatusDateTime)) AS DurationDifference,
    COUNT(*) AS TotalRecords
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    LocationDescription;
```

Comment: That's fantastic man! Didn't even think to use the "second" thing in DATEDIFF. Works beautifully!

Comment: follow up: I'm trying to add a column for the "per second" calculation part. i can't post the modified query as it's too long for comment box, but was simply trying to divide the total records by the durationdifference to get a decimal/int value of "records per second" column as well. Getting all 0 outputs though.

Comment: Use: `1.0 * COUNT(*) / DATEDIFF(second, MAX(StatusDateTime), MIN(StatusDateTime))` ... you need to tell SQL Server to do floating point division rather than integer division.

Answer (score 1):

This meet your requirements.

```
SELECT 
  LocationDescription,
  DATEDIFF(seconds,MAX(StatusDateTime), MIN(StatusDateTime)) AS DurationDifference,
  COUNT(*) AS TotalRecords
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY LocationDescription
```

Comment: I am filled with a strong feeling of Deja vu upon seeing this answer.

Comment: Me also! I hit post and there was your version waiting for me. I've voted you up as I missed the semicolon.